# Как добавить виджет QTextEdit в QTableWidget?

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, qtablewidget, qtextedit

У меня имеется виджет `QTableWidget`, в который нужно добавить определенное количество раз, 
на новую строку, в первый столбец номер строки, 
а во второй новый объект типа `QTextEditor`.

Но количество будет задаваться пользователем. И в последствии нужно будет считать значение каждого из `QTextEditor`.

---

Я попытался это реализовать по средством перебора, но объект не появляется в таблице.

Вот часть кода:

```
for _ in range(self.output_text.count(replacement_symbol)):
    input_replacement = QTextEdit(self.table_of_replacements)
    input_replacement.resize(195, 25)
    self.list_of_replacement.append(input_replacement)
    self.table_of_replacements.setCellWidget(_, 0, input_replacement)
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял какое количество будет задаваться пользователем, но `добавить QTextEdit в QTableWidget` можжно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *


class MyWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget= QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(0, 2)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["номер \nстроки", "Text"])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        self.button = QPushButton("button")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onButton)

        lay = QGridLayout(centralWidget)        
        lay.addWidget(self.textEdit, 1, 0)       
        lay.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 2, 0)    
        lay.addWidget(self.button, 3, 0)         

    def onButton(self):
        listText = self.textEdit.toPlainText().split('\n')
        row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        for r, _text in enumerate(listText):
            it_nn   = QTableWidgetItem("{:>10}".format(r+1))
            it_text = QTableWidgetItem(_text)

            self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount())
            for c, item in enumerate((it_nn, it_text)):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row+r, c, item)        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MyWin()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]